# What kind of tests should I run for my master's thesis?

Tags: regression, econometrics, stata, instrumental-variables, effects

I am analyzing the effect of covid rates and covid lockdown levels on murder and suicide rates for the 50 most populous counties in the U.S. I am not sure what to do to analyze the question in aggregate terms- I have transformed the data into panel data: I have 36 months and 50 counties, so 1800 cells of data for suicide and murder. I also have the covid rates in panel data format as well- what kind of variable could I use for an instrumental variable for a fixed effects regression? or what kind of regression would work better for this question? Thanks!

Comment: Do you at least have a working theory in mind? Id start there rather than chasing trends in your data.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand my current model is: 

Murder Rate_ijt = β_0 + β_1 COVID Rate_ijt + β_2 Lockdown Level_ijt + β_3 Unemployment Rate_ijt + β_4 Civilian Labor Force_ijt + X'_ijtγ + County_i + Time_t + ε_ijt

where Unemployment Rate_ijt and Civilian Labor Force_ijt are the unemployment rate and civilian labor force in county i in month j and time t, respectively.

The same is said for the suicide model

Comment: Perhaps you can edit that into your question.

Comment: What is your hypothesis?

Answer (score 0):

To use two-stage least squares (2SLS) regression for your analysis, you will need an instrumental variable that is strongly correlated with your explanatory variable (i.e., covid rates and covid lockdown levels), but uncorrelated with the error term of your outcome variable (i.e., murder and suicide rates).

One potential instrumental variable for your analysis could be the date that the county implemented its covid lockdown measures. This variable is likely to be strongly correlated with covid rates and lockdown levels, but it may not be directly related to murder and suicide rates.

In terms of methodology, you can just use 2SLS.